# ACRA - How to implement it into an existing project

Tags: android, acra

Hi all first timer here,
I have a project I've been working on and now I wish to integrate ACRA into it. I downloaded the file from google, created a folder lib and imported the jar file into it. I added the INTERNET permission to the manifest, and created a MyApplication class with the suggested code  from http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup into my package as stated in the instructions. Now that I have done all that how do i get it to take effect with my application and am I missing anything? Should I have not created a new class and just added the code into the existing main class?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's not working you sound to of done most things, make your app crash (access a null pointer is easy to add) an see what happens.

Comment: It's not a matter of not working (yet), I don't know how to link the new class created which contains the code from the guide to my main activity class? cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Now that I have done all that how do i get it to take effect with my application and am I missing anything?

If you followed the BasicSetup instructions per your link, then this work is already done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issues was that firstly, I forgot to add android:name="MyApplication" in the application tag in the manifest. Secondly, for some reason for some systems the lib folder needs to be renamed "libs" and then path rebuilt, the process is detailed here: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Cheers